# Spark Streaming: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a simple spark streaming job written in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://master1:7077,master2:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

ssc.socketTextStream("master1", 9999).count().pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

After a couple of seconds of running, task fails. Here is the exception I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:155)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:135)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString_slow(Output.java:420)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:326)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:153)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:146)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dataSerializeStream(BlockManager.scala:1190)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dataSerialize(BlockManager.scala:1199)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putArray(MemoryStore.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:791)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockManagerBasedBlockHandler.storeBlock(ReceivedBlockHandler.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushAndReportBlock(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushArrayBuffer(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl$$anon$3.onPushBlock(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.pushBlock(BlockGenerator.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$receiver$BlockGenerator$$keepPushingBlocks(BlockGenerator.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator$$anon$1.run(BlockGenerator.scala:108)
```

A new task starts after that, so the job keeps running. However, I'd like to know, what am I missing.

**UPDATE**

*spark-defaults.conf*

```
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              4g
spark.executor.memory            4g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails
spark.deploy.recoveryMode        ZOOKEEPER
spark.deploy.zookeeper.url       master1:2181,master2:2181,master3:2181
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Driver or Executor? Seems like you need to increase memory of your executors. Also please mention your cluster configurations.

Comment: I'm seeing this exception in executors. Every executor has 4Gb of RAM. I've updated the question posting my spark-defaults.conf

Comment: what is the size/ type of data received by the Streams in each Batch? In case you have captured GC Logs, the post that too. your program is Simple but seems like velocity of data received data is too high. Do you see anything in Spark-UI like task Backlog, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to spark and not sure what to look for in task backlog. The program is pulling strings of about 1Kb from a network socket. After receiving about 1-3kk of strings, I see that executor exits with "out of memory".

Comment: Also I've tried to double  the memory of executors. The "out of memory" occurs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the executor memory [on the application itself](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/configuration.html#spark-properties):

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://master1:7077,master2:7077")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
```